# Using pandas manipulate number format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

just out of my curiosity, I have a name list with phone numbers in a csv file, and I want to change these phone numbers from ############ (11 digits) to the format of ###-####-####, adding two minus sign in between 3-4 and 7-8 place.

is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

If it's Dataframe you can use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) with `formate string`

```py
df
           num
0  09187543839
1  08745763412

df.num = df.num.apply(lambda x : "{}-{}-{}".format(x[:3],x[3:7],x[7:]))
df
             num
0  091-8754-3839
1  087-4576-3412
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Below is a code-snippet that accomplishes what you want:

```
phone = str(55512354567)

print(f'{phone[:3]}-{phone[3:7]}-{phone[7:]}')
```

You can adapt the above idea to your Pandas dataframe as shown below:

```
# Sample data
data_df = pd.DataFrame([[55512345678], [55587654321]], columns=['phone'])

# Create a string column
data_df['phone_str'] = data_df['phone'].map(lambda x: str(x))

# Convert the column values to the right format
data_df['phone_str'] = data_df['phone_str'].map(lambda x: f'{x[:3]}-{x[3:7]}-{x[7:]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I may not be using pandas but this could potentially work...

```py
n = 3
n1 = 7
str = "12345678901"

l, m, r = str[:n], str[n:n1], str[n1:]
final = l+"-"+m+"-"+r
print(final)
```

Output:

```
123-4567-8901
```